# What is the shortest way to find inverse of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

I know two methods to find the inverse of a matrix already:-

1. Row and Column transformations
2. $A^{-1}= \frac{Adj(A)}{Det(A)}$

I want to know if there's any **shorter method** to do so because these two methods feel very lengthy.

Comment: Gauss-Jordan elimination? e.g., https://www.mathportal.org/linear-algebra/matrices/gauss-jordan.php or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix (or is that what you already mean by "row and column transformations"?)

Comment: What matrix sizes ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust A  3 by 3 matrix

Comment: The fastest method should be LU decomposition. Anyway for the $3\times3$ case, which is tiny, the differences between methods are moderate.

Comment: This question is slightly ambiguous. Are you asking the order of complexity of inverting an $n \times n$? Or are you interested in "concrete" usable algorithms. Regarding the second question: there are lots of algorithms with $O(n^3)$ complexity, like $LU$ or $QR$ factorizations, but giving the fact the complexity of matrix multiplication is an open problem (conjectured optimal $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$) it may be the same for matrix inversion.

Comment: You can look up any book in numerical linear algebra to learn those: https://books.google.fr/books/about/Numerical_Linear_Algebra.html?id=5Y1TPgAACAAJ

Answer (score -1):

I always use the method where you use Gauss row operations against the identity matrix to find the inverse.

Basically you put the matrix you want to know the inverse of, called A, on "the left side" and the identity matrix, called I, "on the right side". Then you use regular Gauss row operations to transfer the identity matrix to the left side and the one you end up with on the right side is your inverse.

Here is an example:
Where A is the matrix and A^-1 is it's inverse.

[image: image of example finding inverse of a matrix]

Comment: I think this is the shortest way of finding it. To know if it exists, just test if the determinant is not equal to zero.

Comment: I got an A in linear algebra and I always use this strategy: 1. check the determinant. I do this fast since it's simple algebra. Then, this method since Gauss operations is easy to follow, I can easily make sure that I did not make any mistakes during the way. So I get the correct inverse. Always.

Comment: I am discussing the computational complexity. If the system is singular, you will see it during Gaussian elimination, so precomputing the determinant is useless overhead. And for a $3\times3$ system, this overhead is significant (by Laplace formula, 9 multiplications and 5 additions).